# Android - Remote service is terminated if application is terminated

Tags: android, service

Android SDK says that [remote service](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.html) runs in another process with the application. I thought it mean if the app stops/ is terminated..., then remote service still remains running. But it does not.

For example I have this remote service:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Service;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class WatchDogService extends Service {

  private Timer timer = new Timer();

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(WatchDogService.class.getName(), "WatchDog start");

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Log.i(WatchDogService.class.getName(), "WatchDog boo boo!!! ^^");
      }
    }, 0, 5000);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(WatchDogService.class.getName(), "WatchDog stop");
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(WatchDogService.class.getName(), "WatchDog has just been called...");
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service
    android:name="WatchDogService"
    android:process=":remote" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="WatchDogService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

In another activity I call it as:

```
startService(new Intent("WatchDogService"));
```

The service starts ok. But if I go to system apps manager, then stop the app, the service is terminated too.

I want to keep the service running even if the app is terminated. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I expected that "service" means service, not "application". I mean, I want something like "Service manager". But I forgot that the Applications settings in Android is for end-users, not coder.

So far, I got my answer.

Comment: I'm not able to understand your solution. Can you please elaborate a bit more? I'm also struggling with the same issue and can't figure it out. If I use the same code (from your question) and run the app, and check running processes on my device, it should show me 2 processes and 1 services (instead of 1 process and 1 service), isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to keep the service running even if the app is terminated. How can I do that?

You don't. If the user terminates your app, your app is terminated, period. The user is in control of their Android device, not you.

Please respect the user's wishes, and try not to build apps that the user will want to force-stop, task-kill, or otherwise get rid of.

Comment: I'm talking technically here, Mister. No thanks. Next time if you could, please try to not answer my questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a service you may create a separate application and invoke it or

Instead of a service you may create a separate background application using AIDL described in this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Note that the AIDL should register a notification with an intent to start the original app when it is done and ask the user if he wishes to act on it.